# React JS, creating a clock timer inside Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a clock timer inside a React component. However I'm having difficulty. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ShowDate />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));

function ShowDate() {
  return {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()};
}

setInterval(ShowDate, 1000);
```

Comment: if I were to remove the whole component and just render the function inside ReactDOM then it works. I'm just trying to learn how to transition that into component.

Comment: This seems pretty non idiomatic to me. Why not setInterval closured to `this.state` and mutate appropiately?

Comment: Can you tell us what error you're getting/more information than just "I'm having difficulty"?

Comment: yes of course, it gives error while compiling. Unexpected token . It points to Date inside ShowDate function.

Comment: @ q.then I am following React tutorial on their official website to do this. The way they show it is by not using component and simply rendering it inside ReactDOM and I want to use component with out including state.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by wrapping the new Date().toLocaleTimeString() in { }?

Comment: I am not quiet sure. It was a desperate attempt trying to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The React tutorial has this example:

```
function tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Most likely, you will avoid writing code like that. See note that follows:

> Note:
>   In practice, most React apps only call ReactDOM.render() once. In the next sections we will learn how such code gets encapsulated into stateful components.
>   We recommend that you don't skip topics because they build on each other.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateDate = this.updateDate.bind(this);
    
    this.state = {
      date: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
    }
    this.interval = setInterval(this.updateDate, 1000);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
  
  updateDate() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.date}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

If you are just following along in the tutorial, your code can be made to work in the same manner as the example:

```js
const App = () => (
  <div>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</div>
);

function tick() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It definitely does work. Is there any way to do this without using state?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help.